# Linux 1604: kestrel service can't find dotnet installation

Tags: linux, .net-core, kestrel

I am getting the following error:

```
Jun 03 06:41:04 {my_digital_ocean_server} systemd[13752]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/dotnet: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /usr/bin/dotnet could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The process /usr/bin/dotnet could not be executed and failed.
```

When running:

```
systemctl start kestrel-hellomvc.service
```

following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction

Running: `nano /usr/bin/dotnet` gets me a large file with content, and `which dotnet` returns
/usr/bin/dotnet, so the file **does** exist(?).

Why am I getting this error, and what is the solution?

EDIT:
My /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-hellomvc.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API Application running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/aspnetcore/hellomvc
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/hellomvc/hellomvc.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10  # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Try to run the `ExecStart` command as root yourself. You may encounter a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Dotnet might not be located in usr/bin. On Ubuntu Server 16.04 mine is located at /usr/share/dotnet and the executable line in the service file is /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
which dotnet
```

to find the correct path for your app service file `/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-MyAppName.service` attribute

```
ExecStart=/bin/dotnet /var/www/dev-slc1.almw.local/public_html/MyAppName.dll
```

For example on CentOS7 `which dotnet` results in above: `/bin/dotnet`.